# Delete item from list in SharePoint using Rest API returns bad request

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I trying to delete an item from SharePoint using the REST API, but it returns bad requests.

My code uses Http Client as follows:

var id = new StringContent(id);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add( new MediaTypeWithQuailtyHeaderValue("application/json"));
MediaTypeWithQuailtyHeaderValue contentType = MediaTypeWithQuailtyHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=verbose");

return await client.PostAsync($"{site}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('{list}')/Items", I'd);

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Add the header they want and form the url they want.  Header: `X-HTTP-Method: "DELETE"` and the url should be /Items(id) with the parens https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-list-items-by-using-rest

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175141/how-to-delete-list-item-using-sharepoint-online-2013-rest-api-in-c-sharp

Comment: Adding the extra headers and changing items (Id) still returned bad request from SharePoint. Nothing seems to work